# Two different Bers embeddings

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

In *An Introduction to Teichmüller spaces* by Imayoshi and Taniguchi, they present in section 6.1.3 the Bers embedding as a map from Teichmüller space of a Riemann surface $X$ to the space of quadratic differentials of $X^{*}$ (the quotient of the lower half plane by the Fuchsian group associated to X). Using a pairing, they identify the **cotangent** space of Teichmüller space at X with the space of quadratic differentials on $X$.

In *A Primer on mapping class groups* by Farb and Margalit, they present in section 11.7 what looks like a Bers embedding as a map from the space of quadratic differentials on $X$ of norm smaller than 1 to the Teichmüller space of $X$. This allows one to identify the **tangent** space of Teichmüller space at $X$ with the space of quadratic differentials on $X$.

My questions are:

1. What is the relation between these two maps? Is one the inverse of the other in some sense?
2. Are these two interpretations of the tangent space of Teichmüller space just a matter of taste?
3. Using the embedding defined in *A Primer on mapping class groups*, does the pullback of the pairing of quadratic differentials give rise to the Weil-Petersson metric?